# Leetcode Solution Explanation

Tags: python-3.x

For the LeetCode Solution for the problem Add two numbers :

```
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        dummyHead = ListNode(0)
        curr = dummyHead
        carry = 0
        while l1 != None or l2 != None or carry != 0:
            l1Val = l1.val if l1 else 0
            l2Val = l2.val if l2 else 0
            columnSum = l1Val + l2Val + carry
            carry = columnSum // 10
            newNode = ListNode(columnSum % 10)
            curr.next = newNode
            curr = newNode
            l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
            l2 = l2.next if l2 else None
        return dummyHead.next
```

How is the dummHead Object getting updated from the 2nd iteration since in the 1st iteration curr is updated to a new object **curr = newNode**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `curr` is assigned the `newNode`, it first gets *mutated* by the previous statement:

```
curr.next = newNode
```

At that moment -- in the first iteration -- `curr` still references the node that `dummyHead` references, and so `dummyHead.next` is a assigned a node reference here. So `newNode` becomes the tail in a linked list.

In the next iterations the same happens with that tail: it gets mutated, and the linked list grows with one more node, ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

During the first iteration, dummyHead is linked to a new node, let's say Node 0.

```
dummyHead.next = Node 0
```

Then during the second iteration, Node 0 will be linked to the new node, Node 1

```
Node 0.next = Node 1
```

By doing so, now when you call dummyHead.next.next, it will give you Node1.

That's how you update the dummyHead object.

It's like :

dummyhead -> Node 0 -> Node 1 -> .... -> The last Node